# Parsing PKCS7 using bouncy castle

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I have received a p7b file from a client which should contain a certificate chain and am trying to extract the certificates from it using bouncycastle.

I am running the latest `1.55` version of bouncy castle and am using the code you see everywhere for this:

```
        byte [] content = ...;
        CMSSignedData data = new CMSSignedData(content);
        Store certStore = data.getCertificates();
        SignerInformationStore signerInfos = data.getSignerInfos();
        Collection<SignerInformation> signers = signerInfos.getSigners();
        List<X509Certificate> result = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
        for (SignerInformation signer : signers) {
            Collection<X509CertificateHolder> matches = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID());
            for (X509CertificateHolder holder : matches) {
                result.add(new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(holder));
            }
        }
        return result;
```

The problem is that the `signers` collection is empty.

Note that I was able to extract them successfully using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in test.p7b -out test.pem
```

But I rather have a clean java-based solution. Am I missing something? Is the `CMSSignedData` not being constructed correctly?

Comment: 'p7b' or 'p7c' is commonly used for a PKCS7/CMS SignedData with null contentInfo and no signerInfo's, _only_ certs and/or CRLs, which _may_ form or contribute to a chain. After `.getCertificates()` iterate over `.getMatches(null)` .